# Excel process to find optimal range to maximize data

Tags: excel, analysis, solver, maximize

I have a spread sheet with 5 columns, A, B, C, D and E, all the same length all containing numerical data.

Columns A, B, and C all have values from -10 to +10, column D is the results. in column E I have an If AND formula that only shows the appropriate result from D if A, B, or C fall within a range. The range is set by separate cells that the IF AND formula references.

I want to find a separate range for each of the 3 columns that will maximize the average in the adjacent column E.  I have tried to use the evolutionary solver but it gives me different results every time. The other solver methods don't seem to work but I am new to the solver function so I may be using it wrong.

An example of the result I am looking for is;
A must be between 0 and 5, B can be between -10 and +10, C is -2 to 0. This criteria maximizes the average in the adjacent cells E.

I dont know if using the solver is the best approach or not to this but if anyone has any advice on how to better approach this problem without tedious trial and error it would be very helpful

My spreadsheet looks as follows:

```
                A |  B  |  C  |  D   |   E
                1    3     4     6       6
                3   -5   -0.2   -2      -2
               0.5  -1     2     1       1
                2    4     6     2       2 
               -1    2     1    10      10

               A    B     C
        Max   10    10    10 
        Min  -10   -10   -10 

    E count: 5 
 E avg: 3.4
```

A B C D are all pasted values, 
E uses an IF statement to check if the relevant column (A B C) are within the specified max and min range, If A B and C are in the range of the MAX and MIN row it posts the value of D in E, other wise it leaves it blank.  I was using the solver to change the values in the MAX / MIN rows to try and find the optimal mix of max and min for ABC that would result in the highest avg for column E.

only constraints i set were the max and min to be within 10 to -10, as well the minimum count being 10, and max must be > min
 (in the actual spreadsheet the data goes on for 100 samples)

Comment: It would be helpful if you give a sample which shows what your data looks, like, with a 2-dimensional layout which mimics an Excel spreadsheet. There are certain things which you don't mention but which seem important: 1) Are the numbers integers or can they be floating point? 2) How are the "results" in column D computed? *What* formula is used in column E? 3) In solver terminology, what are the changing cells? constraint cells? target cell? You have given very little to work with.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect this, thanks!

Comment: I'm starting to get a clear picture. When you say "leave it blank", does that mean that any such cell in column E is treated as a zero in the average or is it *ignored* in the average so that the average is only over the non-blank cells in E?

Comment: It is ignored in the average.  E is simply the value in D if the max and min criteria is met for ABC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this is implemented makes this a nasty problem. The `IF/AND` operations cause this to be highly nonlinear and discontinuous and non-differentiable. I.e. not very easy to optimize using traditional gradient based methods. The evolutionary algorithm looks to me like the correct thing to try. Indeed by default it will use a different seed each time it is run. You can change that in the solver options by setting the `RandomSeed` to a positive number.

I think this problem can be solved as a linear mixed integer programming problem. Requires a little bit of work, but that would make it possible to find guaranteed optimal solutions. I'll see if I can try this out.

The mathematical model is somewhat complex as we need to do several linearizations. Here is what I have:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Notes:

- the variable b indicates if a data cell is too low or too high
- the variable delta indicates if a data row has all its values inside the bounds
- the calculation of the mean is complicated as we divide a variable by a variable, so we need to linearize
- we added that we can set a minimum K of selected rows

Some results for different K:

[image]
[image]
[image]

This dataset is not so interesting. It would be more interesting if increasing the size of min/max window suddenly causes low value points to enter the solution.

Comment: What does the random seed setting do?

Comment: is there another way to implement this you recomend?

Comment: The evolutionary algorithm is a randomized algorithm. Fixing the seed will make sure it will use the same sequence of random numbers.

Comment: wow that is amazing, it will take me some time to understand that.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: That is great work, do you think it would it be too difficult to set a minimum number of samples? In the spreadsheets I intend to use this formula for columns ABC for example would extend for a few hundred rows and I want to find the ranges to maximize the average and ensure there is a minimum number of data points included in the average.

Comment: In the model there is already a `minone` constraint (see the mathematical model). This is to prevent zero elements are selected (the mean would not be defined then). That constraint `minone` can be changed to any number K.

Comment: Thank you, I will try and implement this in excel myself tomorrow. I havent used math this advance in years and am extremely rusty. Hopefully I can figure out how to do it!

Comment: The data set I provided was just an example to illustrate the question.  I am planning on using this for data sets that will contain 100's of rows in each column.  I am going to try and replicate this now but the math is way over my head.  If i cant get it to work would it be possible to get a copy of the spreadsheet you created?

Comment: Sorry, I used an external solver and did not spent the time to translate the equations back into Excel.